# Como ofereço recompensa para uma pergunta?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, recompensa

Muitas vezes a questão não recebe muitas visitas, como faço para oferecer uma recompensa para incentivar as respostas? Desculpa a noobice mas só achei o `pode-se oferecer uma recompensa em 2 dias` e não o botão para oferecer a recompensa lol

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: Olá, Daniela. Certamente a comunidade está feliz com sua participação no site, não apenas para resolver problemas imediatos, mas agora interagindo de uma forma mais específica com a comunidade. Parabéns! Sempre que quiser discutir alguma coisa sobre o [pt.so], pode criar uma pergunta aqui no **Meta**. É como se fosse um site de perguntas dentro do site principal.

Comment: Boa tarde, acredito que tenha que esperar o periodo, por falar nisso qual pergunta? :)

Comment: Entendi, não sabia que tinha que esperar o período! Obrigada. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543894/how-do-i-make-casting-to-basicdblist

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No caso estes 2 dias é o período que você deve esperar para que o botão de lançar a recompensa apareça na pergunta especifica.

> **Nota:** Notei que no [*help*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) está escrito "gratificação" ao invés de "recompensa", isto me confundiu também.

### Quais perguntas se qualificam?

Motivos pelo qual o botão de recompensa não aparece:

- A pergunta não tem 48 horas de existência (dê à comunidade uma chance de responder normalmente à sua pergunta primeiro)
- Você já tem três recompensas pendentes (você somente pode ter três recompensas abertas de cada vez. Para iniciar uma recompensa para esta pergunta, você deverá primeiro conceder pelo menos uma das recompensas anteriores).
- Esta pergunta já tem uma recompensa (para iniciar uma segunda recompensa para esta pergunta, primeiro você deve esperar até que a recompensa atual seja concedida).
  Você não precisa ser o autor da pergunta para oferecer uma recompensa nela.

Um detalhe importante, algumas vezes noto que as pessoas não encontram o link da recompensa, acredito que muitos pensem que ele fica ao lado desses links, abaixo das tags:

> [image: tags e links]

Mas na verdade o link fica abaixo dos comentários, ou seja, se tiver muitos comentários as vezes o link não fica tão evidente/visível, eu mesmo me confundi uma vez com isso em uma postagem com muitos comentários, exemplo:

> [image: link oferecer recompensa]

Comment: Só um aparte. Em breve, esperemos nós, o site deve graduar e a pontuação será a mesma que no SOen.

Comment: O que você considera uma pontuação baixa ? 50 ? 100 ? 150? no caso para a comunidade do SOpt

Comment: @JonathasB.Cavalcante é só medir assim, tem bounty de até 500k, se vc acha que vai precisar usar o bounty pra mais de um tipo de pergunta diferente e vc tem só 150k, com 3 bountys vai se o seu "máximo", se você precisar de mais será necessário mais score, no geral isso nem é regra é só sugestão.