# Perguntas antigas podem ser postadas novamente

Tags: debate, perguntas-sem-resposta

Gostaria de saber, o que pode ser feito nas perguntas antigas e que não foram respondidas. O que acontece com elas? Vamos supor que eu faça uma pergunta que não obtive uma reposta, logo ela é esquecida, eu poderia refaze-lá? Mas eu sei que ela pode ser marcada como um post duplicado, existe algo que possa ser feito quanto a isso?

Comment: O utilizador Comunidade vai pondo perguntas antigas em foco, não sei qual é o critério. Se for mesmo muito antiga e continuar sem resposta tente editá-la de forma a que possa parecer mais clara.

Comment: Relacionado: [Está OK editar uma pergunta só para ter mais visibilidade?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1926/3117)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Não precisa (e nem deve duplica-la), para isto você tem duas opções (a terceira é automatica):

### Editar

Você pode edita-la para tentar melhora-la e torna clara ou interessante (a maneira como é escrita e o título ajudam no entendimento e interesse de outros usuários). Após editar a pergunta vai para primeira posição na página inicial.

Mas lembre-se, se for uma edição que *"não melhore em nada"* só para ir para a página inicial, provavelmente não vai despertar o interesse dos usuários.

### Recompensa

As vezes a pergunta é já é muito boa e não tem muito o que melhorar com edições, mas os usuários não demonstraram interesse por ser uma resposta trabalhosa, neste caso você pode *lançar* uma recompensa de pontos para a pergunta sem resposta, desde que siga estes critérios [Como ofereço recompensa para uma pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2622/3635)

### Edição do usuário [Comunidade♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade)

O usuário [Comunidade♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade) é um usuário robô, que realiza tarefas automaticas ou baseada em uma atividade de um usuário com maior privilégios (como moderadores), a questão é que este usuário eventualmente simula editar perguntas como descrito em [O que significa "modificada pela Comunidade"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1953/o-que-significa-modificada-pela-comunidade), porém não há edição mas a pergunta volta as primeiras posições (primeira página geralmente).

Comment: Eu realizei uma pergunta e melhorei ela várias vezes em intervalos regulares (3 em 3 horas), porém ela não foi pro início da fila. A última vez, foi várias edições bruscas inclusive no título, ela não foi imediatamente para o inicio da fila, mas apareceu entre as primeiras, porém ainda com o título antigo... O SO.pt faz por que isso acontece? O SO.pt faz cache? O.o pergunta em questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69574/interromper-setinterval-com-jquery-mouseup

Comment: Ela foi sim, deve ter sido o cache da sua página, veja: http://i.stack.imgur.com/34mHz.png para fazer um teste, faça o seguinte, abra uma aba com a página inicial do SOpt e outra aba com uma pergunta sua e edite-a, observe o titulo da aba com a página inicial, ele vai aparecer `(1)` na frente, geralmente quando fazemos a edição e não estamos na index ele não atualiza, mas se tiver uma aba já aberta com a index o "verificador de updates" detecta e elimina o cache (suponho). @KaduAmaral

Comment: E no caso de ser uma pergunta feita por alguém não ativo na comunidade? Suponha que quero perguntar se é bom o uso da classe "X" na linguagem "Y" e essa pergunta foi feita por alguém que a muitos meses não aparece no stackoverflow e dificilmente aceitará a resposta. Como fica essa situação?

Comment: @DiChrist o "aceitar" em uma resposta é fundamental, mas não obrigatório, houve duas discussões sobre isto aqui no META: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4097/3635 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4089/3635

Comment: vlw, vou dar uma olhada, mas minha preocupação não é nem mesmo com o aceitar a resposta, mas sim na identificação da resposta mais adequada para o que foi perguntado

Comment: @DiChrist legal o seu interesse, isso é ótimo. Acredito que os upvotes ajudem a determinar o melhor, claro que há exceções, tem resposta que são ruins mas tem upvotes, leve em consideração *upvotes* vs *testes próprios seus* :)

Comment: ah sim, de fato os upvotes ajudam sim. Isso é verdade. Vou dar uma olhada nas discussões postadas