# Recompensas por perguntas podem ser estornadas?

Tags: debate, recompensa

Nunca ofereci recompensas por nenhuma pergunta, até porque, acredito que esse privilégio é para quem tem muita reputação, então minha dúvida refere-se ao estorno dessa recompensa.

#### Caso 1

Caso a pergunta não seja respondida satisfatoriamente pelos outros usuários, a recompensa dada pela aquela pergunta pode voltar para a conta de quem inicialmente ofereceu?

#### Caso 2

O que fazer se usuários usarem de má fé essa funcionalidade do site?
ou seja, usar a recompensa como isca, para atrair respostas de outros usuários, sendo que uma delas responde bem a dúvida, mas o usuário que ofereceu a recompensa não quer marcar como resposta correta, para que o autor da resposta, não receba a recompensa.

Comment: Não, uma vez que você ofereceu a recompensa, os pontos dela não votam a você.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Caso 1

Não, não vai voltar para quem ofereceu (podendo ter sido oferecida pelo autor da pergunta ou por outra pessoa), porque recompensa não é troca de pontos, foi pago para destacar a pergunta e só vai ganhar estes pontos quem responder (com exceção de quem ofereceu) e se quem a ofereceu concordar com a resposta.

Os pontos são para se destacar a pergunta principalmente, se ninguém respondeu até o termino você ainda sim teve a pergunta em destaque, mais detalhes em:

- [Quando eu ofereço uma recompensa, o que na verdade acontece?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2079/3635)
- [Qual garantia eu tenho que vou receber a recompensa se minha resposta estiver correta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5300/3635)
- [Como ofereço recompensa para uma pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2621/3635)

## Caso 2

> ... mas o usuário que ofereceu a recompensa não quer marcar como resposta correta, para que o autor da resposta, não receba a recompensa.

Primeiro note que quem oferece pode não ser o dono da pergunta, portanto ele não pode forçar o dono a marcar uma resposta como correta, outra coisa a resposta correta não necessariamente precisa receber os pontos.

Mesmo que o AP (autor da pergunta) tenha oferecido a recompensa, os pontos são dele, a pergunta também, ele faz como ele quiser e gasta como quiser, o que podemos fazer é votar positivamente na resposta que o autor não quer aceitar, se ela for realmente boa mesmo. Agora digo uma coisa se o AP (autor da pergunta) não aceitou raramente vai ser por má fé, é mais provável que:

- Ele não entendeu a resposta
- Ele não conseguiu resolver seu problema com aquela resposta

Comment: Só para lembrar que nem sempre o AP é quem faz a oferta da recompensa. Tem inclusive uma medalha para você oferecer uma recompensa em uma pergunta de outra pessoa. Então, eu acho que o mais adequado no primeiro parágrafo do caso 2 seria: "não tem o que fazer, os pontos são de quem ofereceu a recompensa, a pergunta é do AP, eles fazem como quiserem e gastam como quiserem..."

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado "você" no caso me referia ao autor mesmo, vou editar.